# Where could I get a tripod for panoramas on iPhone?

Tags: tripod, panorama, iphone

I'm interested in taking great panoramic views.

Photosynth on the iPhone looks pretty cool, but I'd like great looking images so I'm in need of a tripod.

I've seen this one http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87OJo75-knY

Can anyone tell me where I can get this, or recommend another one for panoramas?

Comment: Photosynth stitches the image for you without requiring a tripod, that is the entire beauty of photosynth.

Comment: @dpollitt, yes it is pretty cool, but for the best panoramas the hand needs to be extremely still and rotating around one point like in the video, otherwise sometimes it does some strange stitching

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [GorillaMobile](http://joby.com/gorillamobile). It is very small and light and its flexible legs let you attach it to various objects such as poles, street signs, tree branched, bicycle handles, etc.

EDIT:

[Gary Fong now makes a tripod adapter for the iPhone](http://www.garyfongestore.com/iphone-tripod-mount-429.html#.UG43ztffO4M), meaning you can use your iPhone on any tripod. Plus, the iPhone is so light compared to a camera that any well-constructed tripod will have no problem holding the phone.

Comment: I'm after something that pans and tilts.

Answer (score 3):

This is neat: [The Glif](http://www.theglif.com/) Tripod Mount & Stand For iPhone 4 and 4S

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what that link might lead to and why you think it's neat?

Comment: It is an iPhone tripod, and it is neat. (+1 to mattdm :) )

Comment: Hello Helios, and welcome to PhotoSE. While your answers seem to be useful, they don't quite fit the model of our forum. Rather than simply linking other sites, we prefer to have articles (if there are any) summarized or quoted here. When it comes to equipment, we prefer to have each answer explain why it is a solution to an asked problem. Could you expound a bit on why the Glif is the answer to @raklos' question?

Comment: +1 for the Glif. It's cheap and works on any tripod mount.

Comment: whilst being neat, the glif does not solve the problem. I need something that pans 360 and tilts.

Comment: It literally is neat, it is made by Neat Studios.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Nodal Ninja](http://www.nodalninja.com) will work for you.

It's pretty expensive and you need to adapt it a little to grasp your iPhone, but it's otherwise perfect for what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the Glif is a mighty fine choice, to give you another option there's the XShot [iPhone Case](http://xshot.com/products/xshot-iphone-4-case) which has a tripod attachment. Both are pretty good choices though, but theres quite a few other options out there.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find the one in your video but I think the one in this link pans and tilts around the lens axes in every direction. http://www.youbiq.com/
I am trying to resolve the same problem but wanted a solution that also avoids  photographing the tripod itself. I will probably have to build it. An alternative would be editing the image to remove imperfections like unwanted tripod legs etc Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a panorama mount for the iphone 4 and 4S that works great with Microsoft Photosynth and other apps.

Check it out.

[iClyck iphone panorama mount](http://www.iclyck.com/)

During Oct and Nov 2012 I am running a crowd funding project to make them in quantity.\

[iClyck crowd funding project](http://www.pozible.com/index.php/archive/index/10569/description/0/0)

Answer (score -1):

You could consider using a tripod mount for the iPhone, then you could use any tripod. There are loads of tripod mounts available just try searching 'iphone tripod mount' in Google.